# Manage Azure SAS HTML URL Route with its key

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have static website in azure blocked blob storage. I secure that HTML content with azure Shared Access Storage, but whenever I access one of them page that link to another page that can not be served because that need URL token is there any way to cache that and manage that key with static html content.

Comment: It is not clear how you're securing the landing page via SAS. Can you describe that part?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is generally frown upon in SO, but this question needs an answer beyond what's asked.

In general we do not recommend Azure BLOB storage to host web sites directly from blob storage. Some scenarios call for "direct" blob usage, but those are usually concerned with CDN or similar. Shared Access Signatures (SAS) are there to provide security to the objects stored in blob storageю

Shared Access Signatures, Part 1: Understanding the SAS Model

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/

For the simple static web site hosting scenario we usually recommend to consider Azure Web Apps. Web Apps provide simple and scalable infrastructure to host your static web sites in PaaS model. Sometimes I call it "IIS for hire":

Web Apps overview

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-overview/